Sufficient and necessary conditions for a solution of a certain system of ode's involving the cross product to be defined on the sphere $\mathbb{S}^2$
Consider the system of equations on $p,v: I\to \mathbb{R}^3$
\begin{align*}
p'&= -a v+b \cos(ct+d) (p\times v),\\
v'&= ap+ b\sin (ct+d) (p\times v),
\end{align*}
for constants $a,b,c,d\in \mathbb{R}$ with $ab\neq 0$.
It's not difficult not see that this system admits existence and uniqueness of solutions, given initial conditions $p(t_0)=p_0$ and $v(t_0)=v_0$ on some $t_0\in I$. Basically this remark follows the same reasoning of my answer for this question.
However, unlike the question mentioned above, it's not quite the same to show that the solution lies on the unit sphere if the initial conditions are orthonormal. More precisely,

Question. Suppose the initial conditions are orthonormal, i.e. $p_0,v_0\in \mathbb{S}^2$ and $\langle p_0,v_0\rangle =0$. What are the necessary and sufficient conditions on $a,b,c,d\in \mathbb{R}$ in order for the (unique) solution to satisfy $p,v:I\to \mathbb{S}^2$ and $\langle p,v\rangle \equiv 0$ on $I$?

What I've tried:
Of course, the first idea is to take the derivatives of the functions $\langle p,p\rangle$, $\langle v,v\rangle$, $\langle p,v\rangle$ and use the equations and initial conditions. However, doing this didn't helped as I expected. The best I could get was
\begin{align*}
(\langle p,p\rangle+\langle v,v\rangle)' &= 2\langle p',p\rangle +2\langle  v',v\rangle= -2a\langle p,v\rangle +2a\langle p,v\rangle =0.
\end{align*}
Therefore, we must have $\langle p,p\rangle +\langle v,v\rangle$ constant and, by initial conditions, this constant must be $2$. But this doesn't tell us yet that $\langle p,p\rangle =\langle v,v\rangle=1$. As for the other mentioned derivatives, we have
\begin{align*}
\langle p,p\rangle' &= 2\langle p,p'\rangle =-2a\langle p,v\rangle\\
\langle v,v\rangle' &= 2\langle v,v'\rangle = 2a\langle p,v\rangle \\
\langle p,v\rangle' &= \langle p',v\rangle +\langle p,v'\rangle = a(\langle p,p\rangle -\langle v,v\rangle)
\end{align*}

I think I've made it.
The derivative of $\langle p,v\rangle$ shows that $\langle p,v\rangle$ is $\mathcal{C}^\infty$. Then, taking the second derivative, we get
\begin{align*}
\langle p,v\rangle ''&= a(\langle p,p\rangle'-\langle v,v\rangle')= -4a^2\langle p,v\rangle.
\end{align*}
Therefore, $\langle p,v\rangle$ is a solution of the equation $u''=-4a^2 u$. Now, this has general solution given by
$$u(t) = c_1 \cos (2 a t)+c_2\sin(2at).$$
Evaluating on $t_0\in I$ we get $0=\langle p_0,v_0\rangle = c_1 \cos(2at_0)+c_2\sin (2at_0)$. As for the first derivative, we have
\begin{align*}
2a(-c_1\sin (2at)+c_2\cos (2at))&=\langle p,v\rangle' = a(\langle p,p\rangle -\langle v,v\rangle).
\end{align*}
Again, evaluating this on $t_0\in I$ and using our orthonormality hypothesis and that $a\neq 0$, we get $-c_1\sin (2at_0)+c_2\cos (2at_0) =0$. Now, this shows us that $(c_1,c_2)$ is orthogonal to both $(\cos(2at_0),\sin (2at_0))$ and $(-\sin(2at_0),\cos(2at_0))$ and therefore must be equal to $(0,0)$.
But then, this gives us $\langle p,v\rangle \equiv 0$.
The remainder follows from there: $\langle p,p\rangle ' = -2a\langle p,v\rangle =0$ and similarly $\langle v,v\rangle '=0$, so both $\langle p,p\rangle$ and $\langle v,v\rangle$ must be constant equal to one.
